# Can I use smstp.gmail.com as mail server in UTL_MAIL?

Tags: oracle11g, smtp, utl-mail

I want to send mail using UTL_MAIl package in Oracle 11g. It is possible to use "smtp.gmail.com" google imap server as my SMTP server for this? please help?

```
BEGIN
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER SESSION SET smtp_out_server = ''smtp.google.com''';
UTL_MAIL.send(sender => 'sheran.ewisl@gmail.com',
recipients => 'mail@susantha.net',
subject => 'Test Mail',
message => 'Hello World',
mime_type => 'text; charset=us-ascii');
END;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it cannot possible with Oracle 11g express edition where we will need to authenticate smstp.google.com and to this we have to obtain certificate and have to register on oracle server using oracle wallet , but in oracle express edition there is no functionality to create wallet but using wallet manages then u can use it with express edition ,this method suggested on a blog and i still got  chance to do that , until then its not possible on oracle free version but on paid version possible. :)